# Is it discouraged to use a sans-serif font for a scientific thesis?

Tags: thesis, latex, design

I'm currently working on my bachelor's thesis in Computer Science at a European university. I've been fiddling around with the layout a lot recently, and specifically tried out using fonts other than the default one that comes with LaTeX [(Computer Modern)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern). I found some sans-serif fonts, e.g. Fira Code or Karmilla, to be very easy to read and pleasing to the eye. I haven't checked with my advisors yet, but I'm almost certain they won't mind -- of course, I will still double check with them before handing in my final draft. There are no specific design guidelines set by my university in regards to fonts either.

**Are there any other reasons to avoid using custom fonts, specifically sans-serif ones, when writing a thesis or dissertation?**

Comment: Especially the comments on [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/26890/68109).

Comment: @GoodDeeds thank you, this makes me even more confident that it's okay to use fonts other than Computer Modern, especially considering that there is no template my university provides for theses. However I'm still wondering if it might be considered unprofessional to choose a different font.

Comment: It does not have to be computer modern, but for longer texts like a thesis, a serif font is much easier to read. There are many nice serif fonts out there.

Comment: I'll note that this site uses a san-serif font. Readers frequently complain that long posts without frequent paragraph breaks (wall of text) are very difficult to read and understand. A serif font might partly correct for that having more "redundant" visible signals about the text. (That isn't the only reason of course.)

Comment: Will your sans-serif font adequately distinguish III from Ill? And rn from m? If so, you have my blessing to use it.